# How do I hide the status bar of a pushed view controller in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, pushviewcontroller, uistatusbar

I have a signup form that pops up when a button is tapped.
My aim is to hide the status bar when this modal is popped up.

Here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)tappedJoinButton:(id)sender {

    if (![PFUser currentUser]) {

        PFSignUpViewController *signUpViewController = [[PFSignUpViewController alloc] init];
        [signUpViewController setDelegate:self]; // Set ourselves as the delegate

        // Present the sign up view controller
        [self presentViewController:signUpViewController animated:YES completion:NULL];
    }
}
```

I have set View controller-based status bar appearance to yes in my plist file. Now I'd like to choose where I hide the status bar. In this situation I'd like to hide it in the signUpViewController that pops up.

I haven't seen any answers on here showing how to hide it in a pushed view controller.

How do I achieve this?

Kind regards

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO]; Try this code...

Comment: [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to hide status bar for only one ViewController the do this:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

}


- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO];
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}
```

For your case it will be in `PFSignUpViewController`.

Hope this helps .. :)

Comment: How am I accessing my viewWillAppear method? This signUpViewController is created in code. How do I access it from within the tappedJoinButton method? This where I am stuck.

Comment: @LondonGuy >> check if there is any property for hiding status bar or you can make a subclass of signUpViewController (without status bar). Then you can access the property of PFSignUpViewController. In that class you can declare these or prefersStatusBarHidden method.

Comment: I just created a new class which was a subclass of PFSignUpViewController and then created an instance of that. In the new class I set preferred status hidden method to return yes and it worked fine.

Comment: @londonGuy >> Nice to hear that. :)

Comment: This API is deprecated

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

in `viewDidload` of `PFSignUpViewController`

```
 if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)]) {
    // iOS 7
    [self performSelector:@selector(setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate)];
} else {
    // iOS 6
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```

paste this function in controller

```
- (BOOL)prefersStatusBarHidden {
return YES;
}
```

Comment: How do I access viewDidLoad of PFSignUpViewController?

Answer (score 0):

you lust like ....

```
if ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarHidden != hideStatusBar)
{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:hideStatusBar withAnimation:UIStatusBarAnimationSlide];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your viewWillAppear...

```
       [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```

Or try This method ....

```
       -(void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)
   navigationController willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)
   viewController animated:(BOOL)animated

       {
          [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this "View controller-based status bar" appearance in the plist and set NO

```
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES];
```